# Failure in shared library initialization on Linux

Tags: java, c, linux

I'm writing a shared library in linux, and i have a constructor

```
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) od_init(void);
```

In od_init I initialize my lib with some data i bring from configuration file.
My problem, is how to make failure handling in case the config file is corrupted or not found or whatever, since  **attribute** ((constructor)) returns void and gets void.
Later i use this shared lib from my java code, and i load it with the following command :

```
System.loadLibrary("od_jni");
```

and i want this call to look like this :

```
try
{
    System.loadLibrary("od_jni");
}
catch
{
  .....
}
```

Is there some tricks to make the user of the library understand that something went wrong ?

P.S. Google did not show good results for my question.

Your thoughts and suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t write a library initializer that can fail. Think about how a native program would work when being linked against such a library. It would struggle handling such a failure too. Just provide an explicit initialization method and call it from the Java side after loading the library. This explicit initialization method can return arbitrary values or even throw exceptions via JNI.

Comment: Not that clean as I wanted it to be, but looks like there is no other way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Better yet, take this as a hint to have an _object_ contain your data, rather than having it be a static-duration variable in the library.